# Recognizing tree with node depths textually stated in ANTLR4

Tags: tree, antlr4

I'm trying to parse some input text that describes a tree.

To better explain the problem, I'm not start with the text, but with the intended result:

[image: Intended tree]

This tree could be written as a parenthesized expression (for example):

```
node-0 (node-00 (node-000 node-001 node-002) node-01 (node-010 (node-0100) node-011) node-02)
node-1 (node-10)
```

Which is very simple to recognize using ANTLR4:

```
grammar ParenthesizedDepthGrammar;

WS : (' '|'\n') -> channel(HIDDEN);

TEXT : [-A-Za-z0-9]+;

root: item*;

item:
    TEXT ('(' item+ ')')?
    ;
```

Now the problem is my input describes the tree not as a parenthesized expression. Instead each node is given a number, which states its depth, and it implicitly belongs to the nearest previous node whose depth is shallower. Like this:

```
1 node-0
2 node-00
3 node-000
3 node-001
3 node-002
2 node-01
3 node-010
4 node-0100
3 node-011
2 node-02
1 node-1
2 node-10
```

I thought the following grammar would correctly recognize it:

```
grammar TextualDepthGrammar;

WS : (' '|'\n') -> channel(HIDDEN);

LEVEL : [0-9]+;
TEXT : [-A-Za-z0-9]+;

root: item[0]*;

item[int parentLevel] returns [int level]:
    LEVEL
    { $level = $LEVEL.int; }
    { $level > $parentLevel }?
    TEXT
    item[$level]*
    ;
```

However it does not.

The semantic predicate `{ $level > $parentLevel }?` correctly cuts the parsing, but `LEVEL` is already consumed, and the grandparent tree node get no chance to try parsing new children.

I think it needs either:

1. to rewind the lexer to "unconsume" the `LEVEL`; or
2. to readahead `LEVEL` at the very beginning of `item` rule and bail if it is not deeper than parent.

**But how?**

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this using `getCurrentToken()` to peek (readahead) the next token:

```
grammar TextualDepthGrammar;

WS : (' '|'\n') -> channel(HIDDEN);

LEVEL : [0-9]+;
TEXT : [-A-Za-z0-9]+;

root: item*;

item:
    LEVEL
    TEXT
    (
        { Integer.parseInt(getCurrentToken().getText()) > $LEVEL.int }?
        item
    )*
    ;
```

For the input:

```
1 node-0
2 node-00
3 node-000
3 node-001
3 node-002
2 node-01
3 node-010
4 node-0100
3 node-011
2 node-02
1 node-1
2 node-10
```

It correctly gave:

```
(root 
  (item 1 node-0 
    (item 2 node-00 
      (item 3 node-000) 
      (item 3 node-001) 
      (item 3 node-002)
    ) 
    (item 2 node-01 
      (item 3 node-010 
        (item 4 node-0100)
      ) 
      (item 3 node-011)
    ) 
    (item 2 node-02)
  ) 
  (item 1 node-1 
    (item 2 node-10)
  )
)
```

**Though I find using `getCurrentToken()` a bit hackish.**

**What if the decision was to depend on a further token?**

**What if there were optional tokens from the current token to the token were the decision is to be made?**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have fixed all grammar generation errors and warnings, or are certain that they are inconsequential.  The `TEXT` rule should be giving an incomplete range warning.  To include a literal hyphen in a set, it has to be the last element

```
TEXT : [A-Za-z0-9-]+;
```

In order to ensure that all input is considered by the parser, you need to affirmatively match the EOF token

```
root: item* EOF;
```

The way Antlr works, the lexer will consume all of the input before the first parser rule is evaluated.  There is no easy (or intended) way for the parser to otherwise control operation of the lexer.

The idiomatic way of doing what you appear to be trying to do is to parse and generate a tree of the entire input text.  In a tree walker, you can then analyze the tree subject to any set of chosen constraints.  Multiple walkers can be used for different constraint sets all without requiring regeneration of the tree.

Comment: The TEXT lexer rule, with the hyphen at the beginning, works fine. No error, no warning. I'm just used to match hyphen inside character class this way because some other implementations (vi? grep? sed? I don't know) requires it.

Comment: For your second tip, I think I'm better with the answer I posted previously (using `getCurrentToken()`), at least until I face some situation like those I've put on the questions at the end. Parsing it once, then walking the tree to correct it seems to be a waste of ANTLR4 power.